# What will be faster in UPDATE: COALESCE(field,value) or WHERE field is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, coalesce

What query should be faster

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = COALESCE(field1, someValue)
WHERE foreignKeyField = someKeyValue
```

or

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = someValue
WHERE foreignKeyField = someKeyValue AND field1 is null
```

in MS SQL Server? What does it depend on?

Comment: 2nd query should be faster as less number of rows are encountered. But still the difference can be noticed only when you have millions of records

Comment: It depends on how many rows in the table, how many of these satisfy the _full_ condition, and whether you have any indexes

Answer (score 4):

`ISNULL` will have less overhead, depends on NULL conditions, i guess. Here is the test comparision of COALESCE vs. ISNULL vs. IS NULL OR -- http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2004/03/01/189.aspx

Also, check out this blog for Performance comparion:ISNULL vs. COALESCE 
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce.aspx which says  :

> ISNULL appears to pretty consistently out-perform COALESCE by an
>   average of 10 or 12 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me first state that your queries have 2 different meanings.  Updating table1 and setting field1 equal to something always, even if it's NULL, is not equivalent to updating the table only where field1 is NULL.  What are your intentions on your update?

Take this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e404/2) for example:

```
SELECT Field FROM Test WHERE Field IS NULL;
SELECT COALESCE(Field,'') FROM Test;
```

The first query returns a single record and the second returns 2 records.

You may be wondering about the performance of:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field,'') FROM Test;
SELECT ISNULL(Field,'') FROM Test;
```

Although I haven't tested it, ISNULL is suppose to be 20-30% more efficient.

Hope some of this helps.  Good luck.

Comment: The task is to set someValue at field1 to all records in table1, where field1 is null. If I'm not mistaking both queries solve that task correctly, because COALESCE(field1,someValue) returns field1 value if it is not null, and someValue otherwise. But I wonder which is faster.